# Set img src of another page using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the src of an image using javascript. The image and the javascript function are in different html pages.
The javascript function is given below

```
     <html>
     <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function changeImage(newSrc)
     {
     document.getElementById(dp).src = newSrc;
     }
     </script>
     <title>Socialize-Home</title>
     </head>
     <body>
     <img id="img1" src = "home images\student1.JPG" onclick="changeImage(this.src)"></img>
     </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

The image of another page is given below

```
<img id="dp" src="home images\unknown user.JPG" alt="Your browser doent support this           
          image !" height="25%" width="15%"/>
```

Comment: You say the image is in a "different html page" - is this a window you have opened (through JavaScript), an IFrame or a window that a user might have open?

Comment: yes using ajax- img is in the main (parent) page js function is in the so called child page

Comment: If you're using AJAX, it puts the second page *into* the first. There is therefore no need to do anything special. The AJAX'd in content is *inside* the page and so can be accessed how you would normally access elements.

Comment: SO my above code should work right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using AJAX, it puts the second page into the first. There is therefore no need to do anything special. The AJAX'd in content is inside the page and so can be accessed how you would normally access elements.

Therefore your idea *should* work. However, you have a slight syntax error:

```
document.getElementById(dp).src = newSrc;
```

should be:

```
document.getElementById('dp').src = newSrc;
```

`dp` is a string, you haven't defined a variable called `dp`.

On a side note, the `alt` tag for an image isn't really anything to do with your browser "not supporting" images. The `alt` text is displayed if the image is missing or if the user is visually impaired and is using a screen reader.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some reference to the other window, for instance you can have the window set `opener.childwindow = self` in the window with the target image. Or whatever you have to do.

Then it's just `referenceToOtherWindow.document.getElementById('dp').src = newSrc;`

Comment: i went thru a page about window.opener (dint have any idea till now abt it) though i understood i m not able to implement it in my code

Comment: the image is in the so called parent window, using ajax m opening another page which has this js function